# Is lazy initialization worthy to be for small piece of code?

Tags: java, memory-management, lazy-initialization

I have *singleton* `A.class`. `Runnable loadTask` may be evoked or not, that's why I'm thinking about lazy initialization. I'm concerned about memory usage. So the question is **Does lazy initialization worthy to be implemented**? Or memory for *function body* consumes *little more* then memory for instant initialization and easier to ignore memory consumption difference.

I understand that **the definition of the function MUST consumes memory somewhere**.

P.S. I understand that memory for function body is not allocated in Heap.

P.S. Instrumentation.class, sizeOf, Runtime.freeMemory() works with class fields/attributes only.

```
class A_LazyInit {
    Runnable loadTask;
    void load() {
        if(loadTask == null) loadTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                loadFileFromInternet();
            }
        };
        new Thread(loadTask).start();
    }
    void useMethod() {
        if(isGoodCondition()) load();
    }
}
```

vs

```
class A {
    Runnable loadTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            loadFileFromInternet();
        }
    };
    void useMethod() {
        if(isGoodCondition()) new Thread(loadTask).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lazy initialization is worthwhile for two reasons:  1) It applies to a data structure that will only be used in relatively rare circumstances, and hence the savings in terms of storage and/or setup cost is worth it.  2) You're too lazy to go back and modify the app startup code to init the structure on startup (or whenever the environment is present that allows initialization).  Both are valid reasons for using the technique.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be saving any memory with lazy initialization here. The memory for the code will be reserved whether or not you initialize it eagerly (it's allocated when the class is loaded).

Since initializing your loadTask variable won't take long, using lazy initialization doesn't give you an advantage here in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the fact that classes are lazily initialized already.

You could just doing this

```
enum Singleton {
     INSTANCE;

     Singleton() {
         loadFileFormTheInternet();
     }
}
```

This is thread safe and lazy loaded.